# PHP's $_FILES["file"]["name"] not functioning properly

Tags: php, html, forms, file

Last time I asked a question here I messed up but I think I got it now.  Please let me know if I can ask better :D

I am using an HTML form with PHP and am trying to get a file name.  I am using Bootstrap for the formatting, my Form looks like this:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="file" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Picture</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input style="margin-top: 7.5px;" type="file" name="file" id="file" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then directly after that code I have this:

```
<?php echo "File: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"]; ?>
```

Which upon first visiting the page outputs just (which is correct):

```
File:
```

However after I select a file and hit submit the php code at the end still only outputs "File: "

Anyone know why this is happening?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing your `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your `<form>` tag. Without it the file will not upload.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" 
    class="form-horizontal" action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> method="post">
```