# image uploader not working

Tags: php, sql, file-upload

I'm trying to build an image uploader for a website, however only the part where the no image is selected is working, when an image is selected, this is ignored and no image is uploaded. Tried to figure out what is wrong but can't locate the error.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_testimonial'])) {
$namesurname = (isset($_POST['namesurname']) ? $_POST['namesurname'] :   null);
$title = (isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : null);
$page = (isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] : null);
$content = (isset($_POST['content']) ? $_POST['content']:null);
include 'connect.php';

if (empty($_FILES["test_image"]["name"])) {
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO testimonials (pageID, title, imageURL, content, client_name) VALUES (?, ?, 'media/images/smileydude.png', ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss',$page, $title, $content, $namesurname);
} 
if (!empty($_FILES["test_image"]["name"])) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["test_image"]["tmp_name"], "../media/images/".$_FILES["test_image"]["name"]))
    $imageURL = "media/images/" .$_FILES["test_image"]["name"];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO testimonials (pageID, title, imageURL, content, client_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $page, $title, $imageURL, $content,  $namesurname);      
}
$stmt->execute();
$conn->close();
echo $imageURL;

}   
?>
```

Html code

```
<form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="input-short">                   
                        <p>Name & Surname of Client</p>
                        <input name="namesurname" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-short">                   
                        <p>Company Name / Comment Title </p>
                        <input name="title"  id="company-name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-short">                   
                        <p>Client Type</p>
                        <select name='page'><option value=2>About</option>
 <option value=3>Brand Promotions</option>
  <option value=4>Corporate Services</option>
 <option value=5>Entertainment Services</option>
  <option value=6>After Glow Animation</option>
 </select>                      </div>
                    <div id="input-long">
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <textarea name="content"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image-display"><img src="../media/images/smileydude.png"/>
                    <label class="myLabel" id="uploader">
                    <input type="file"  name="test_image" id="fileToUpload" />
                    <span>Select Image</span>
                    </label> </div>
                <button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_testimonial">Submit Testimonial</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP's $\_FILES\["file"\]\["name"\] not functioning properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519504/phps-filesfilename-not-functioning-properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form from

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

where **enctype="multipart/form-data"** is necessary for file uploads